# Automatically choose between pass by value and pass by reference

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming

I have a class with a template parameter T. Some function of the class get a parameter with type T. To achieve a maximum speed, I want to pass it by value if T is a built in type and pass it by const reference in other cases. I know that this is achievable with some template meta programming, but I am looking for some kind of feature in the standard C++ library (C++11 is also welcomed) what support it (in compile time), or make it easier to implement.

I want to write a code like this, where get_type is T if T is a built in type and get_type is const T& if T is anything else:

```
template <typename T> void foo(get_type<T> a);
```

P.S.: I know Loki (http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/) have a function for it, but I don't want to make my code dependent on an external library.

Comment: Not exactly the same problem but the answers answer my problem too. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the execution speed depends not on the fact that a type is a built in type. From looking into the assembler output of compiled code I believe that is important that data can passed via cpu registers instead of a copy on the stack. So it depends on the cpu architecture, the compiler itself and the amount of parameters you need for your function. As an example: If you have a 8 bit cpu like an avr and you pass a 32bit int value, the compiler could use 4! registers OR it can use a stack frame and a pointer to it.

From my experience the only fact which helps to speed up the things automatically is to look at the amount of data which must be passed to a function. If more than one register is involved it *can* be useful to pass a reference. But still it depends on architecture and compiler and compiler settings as well.

For a first attempt you can try to simply get the size of the parameter as criteria. If the size is bigger than n cpu registers you can specialize your template for reference passing. This can be done simply by using SFINAE and the std::enable_if(sizeof(T)>x)

As a second chance you can have a look at std::is_xxx. There are a lot of predefined templates such as std::is_fundamental. You can combine any of std::is_xxx. See: 
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits

Comment: I am using this code as the first attempt:
`template <typename T> using parameter_type = std::conditional<std::is_scalar<T>::value, T, std::add_const<std::add_lvalue_reference<T>>>;`

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing in the standard C++ library, but there is [`boost::call_traits::param_type`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/utility/call_traits.htm) which does what you want.